# libre office copy formatting Ctrl+Shift+C alternative

Tags: shortcut-keys, libreoffice

Microsoft Word has a very useful command for copying and pasting formatting. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Is there such a command available in LibreOffice Writer? If not, is there some way of adding it?

Comment: Is [Paste Special](http://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Pasting_Contents_in_Special_Formats) what you are looking for? I thought pasting preserved formatting by default.

Comment: No, not just Paste Special. Ctrl+Shift+C will just copy the formatting of the selected text. Ctrl+Shift+V will then copy the formatting onto the (some other) selected text.

Comment: There are quite a few features present in MS Office that aren't (yet) available in LibreOffice. Copying and pasting formats seems to be one of them. In both Calc and Writer, Ctrl+Shift+C is unassigned. You can see the "bindings" in Tools, Customize, Keyboard tab. And in both Calc and Writer, Ctrl+Shift+V is "paste special". I even checked the LibreOffice [extensions site](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center) but came up empty.

Answer (score 5):

Just to clarify **it is possible**, you just have to set the shortcut:

```
 Tools -> Customize (Keyboard Tab)
```

Then you can search for the command 'Clone' which is in:

```
 Edit -> Clone
```

And set the shortcut you want, for example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

[Customize menu, Keyboard tab. Clone command selected and Ctrl+Shift+C shortcut assigned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g1Vs.png)

(The image is in Spanish but I think it still serves its purpose)

**Notice this command will work in a different way**, when you activate it the clone tool will be activated. So:

> 1. Select the target text from which you want to copy the format.
> 2. Activate the tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>), the cursor will change.
> 3. Select the target text to paste the format.

That's it! You're ready to copy those formats!

---

**Warning**:
What I haven't been able to perform is multiple format pasting with a keyboard shortcut, for that you need to use the button with a double-click.

Answer (score 2):

[Format Paintbrush](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Copying_Attributes_With_the_Format_Paintbrush) is your friend:

[image: it is just next to Undo]

You can set a (custom) shortcut key to it if you don‘t like clicking it:
from the menu, choose Tools - Customize - [Keyboard](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Keyboard) tab (a document must be opened)

Comment: Format Paintbrush can not be found in the tab.

Answer (score 2):

There still (2018) is no keyboard shortcut / key combination to accomplish what you want. My current workaround is to draft the document in G Suite docs using the incredibly helpful keyboard combination control-alt-c. Perhaps the developers at Libreoffice could copy the code from G Suite docs, seeing as how it is open-source and all.

Comment: Yes.. Its a shame